# split a string from end till second space

Tags: javascript, html, string, strsplit

I have a string i want to split it so that I can extract the name from the particular string.

```js
let str = "CN=John Mcclau - i0c00cu,OU=PET_Associates,OU=Users,OU=PET,DC=officecabs,DC=SAT-PET,Dt=com";

let splitstr= str.substr(3, str.indexOf(' -'))
console.log(splitstr)

Sample str2 = "PN=Coey PT - ljooys4,OU=PET_Associates,OU=Users,OU=PET,DC=officecabs,DC=SAT-PET,Dt=com";
```

I am doing this way but it displays the " - " too. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split twice, first on the '=' and taking the second index then on the '-' and taking the first index. Add a `trim()` and you're good to go

```js
const getName = str => str.split('=')[1].split('-')[0].trim();

let str = "CN=John Mcclau - i0c00cu,OU=PET_Associates,OU=Users,OU=PET,DC=officecabs,DC=SAT-PET,Dt=com";
console.log(getName(str))

str2 = "PN=Coey PT - ljooys4,OU=PET_Associates,OU=Users,OU=PET,DC=officecabs,DC=SAT-PET,Dt=com";
console.log(getName(str2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch out `substr()` for `slice()` it works fine using the same start/end indices

```js
const getName = str => str.slice(3, str.indexOf(' -'));

const str ='CN=John Mcclau - i0c00cu,OU=PET_Associates,OU=Users,OU=PET,DC=officecabs,DC=SAT-PET,Dt=com',
str2 = "PN=Coey PT - ljooys4,OU=PET_Associates,OU=Users,OU=PET,DC=officecabs,DC=SAT-PET,Dt=com";


[str,str2].forEach(s=> console.log(getName(s)))
```